# Picasso PlaceHolder Image : OutOfMemory

Tags: android, picasso

I am working with Android `Picasso` Library and after setting image from `drawable` folder in `placeholder`,I am getting **outOfMemory** exception. Do `picasso` place holder image stays in memory, If yes then how to remove `placeHolder` image when actual image is loaded?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31993581/1157879)

Comment: Are you using samsung ? if yes, create you drawable placeholder for each density( hdpi, xhdpi etc).

Comment: Obviously this comment is out of subject, but I prefer glide than Picasso. Reasons being https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: Check the Leak Canary. This may help you to ou every leaks on your aplication

Comment: Compressing the placeholder image and keeping in different density folder worked for now, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try resizing your placeholder image since it might be to big and causing OutOfMemory, but it can be also more complex error not only of placeholder. And maybe it's not the problem of placeholder but of current image loaded from url which is too big? You can resize this image with below code:

```
picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(someUrl)
        .resize(sizeX, sizeY)
        .placeHolder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I am resizing the image which is loaded from url, earlier this error was not show but when I add place holder image after that am getting this error, and does adding resize before placeholder resize placeholder image?

Comment: This only resize your image from url. For placeholder you should do on your own. In which folder you keep drawable?

Comment: Compressing the placeholder image and keeping in different density folder worked for now, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because system try to Scale it according to density of the device .The solution worked for me is to create a folder named `drawable-nodpi` inside your res folder . Then put your placeholder image into that folder .

Let me know if it works .