# RecyclerView adapter not found, skipping layout

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make an android app. It has a `recyclerView` being filled with data from a `JSON object` form https://newsapi.org/v1/sources into `cardviews`. I had done this project before, and it ran perfectly. But when I repeated the same code as I had accidentally deleted that project. I am not able to trace my error.

When I run the app, I get the following error.

> 03-17 21:55:36.706 22896-22896/com.example.user.samplebulletin E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   03-17 21:55:36.774 22896-22896/com.example.user.samplebulletin W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

I do remember I had added a `@requiresapi` tag to some functions, but I don't remember which ones.

After I run the `JSON request`, I receive the `JSON object` and parse it perfectly(checked by logging). But I get this error

> 03-17 21:58:01.936 22896-22896/com.example.user.samplebulletin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.user.samplebulletin, PID: 22896
>                                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 506340012 byte allocation with 4409258 free bytes and 185MB until OOM
>                                                                                        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>                                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>                                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
>                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:724)
>                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:575)
>                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
>                                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:167)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:155)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                                                        at com.example.user.samplebulletin.NewsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:33)
>                                                                                        at com.example.user.samplebulletin.NewsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:19)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6321)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5509)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5394)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5390)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1533)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1496)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:593)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3537)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3266)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3798)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>   03-17 21:58:01.937 22896-22896/com.example.user.samplebulletin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2354)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2081)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6348)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

I am not using bitmap and have never faced this error the first time.

**NewsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.user.samplebulletin;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String jsonUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=bdba5de1b490495796a1595f77ed3f37";
    RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_source);

        rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.news_recyclerview);

        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(NewsActivity.this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemThatWasClickedId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemThatWasClickedId == R.id.refresh) {
            new NewsDownloader(NewsActivity.this, jsonUrl, rv).execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**NewsAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.user.samplebulletin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by User on 16-03-2017.
 */

public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsViewHolder> {

    String TAG = "Not Bla";
    Context c;
    ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItems;

    public NewsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItems) {
        this.c = c;
        this.newsItems = newsItems;
    }

    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: ");
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.card_news, parent, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: ");
        NewsItem item = newsItems.get(position);

        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
        holder.author.setText(item.getAuthor());
        holder.date.setText(item.getPublishedAt());

        Picasso.with(c)
            .load(item.getUrlToImage())
            .error(R.drawable.image_not_found)
            .into(holder.image, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsItems.size();
    }
}
```

**NewsParser.java**

```
Context c;
String jsonData;
RecyclerView rv;
String TAG = "NOT bla bla";
NewsAdapter adapter;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItems= new ArrayList<>();

//String id, name, description, url, category, langCode, contCode, smallLogoUrl, medLogoUrl, largeLogoUrl;

public NewsParser(Context c, String jsonData, RecyclerView rv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
    this.rv = rv;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return parse();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Please wait...");
    pd.setMessage("Loading list of news newsItems");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isParsed) {
    super.onPostExecute(isParsed);

    pd.dismiss();
    if(isParsed){
        //bind
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(c, newsItems);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
    }else
        Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private boolean parse(){
    try{
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("articles");
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        newsItems.clear();
        Log.d(TAG, object.toString());

        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){ //jsonArray.length()

            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Log.d(TAG, "parse: ");
            String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            String description = jsonObject.getString("description");
            String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
            String urlToImage = jsonObject.getString("urlToImage");
            String publishedAt = jsonObject.getString("publishedAt");

            String printThis = "New news :\nauthor"+author+"\ntitle"+title+"\ndescription"+description+"\nurl"+url+"\nurlToImage"+urlToImage+"\npublishedAt"+publishedAt;
            Log.d(TAG, printThis);
            newsItems.add(new NewsItem(author, title, description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt));
        }
        return true;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**NewsDownloader.java**

```
package com.example.user.samplebulletin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by User on 16-03-2017.
 */

public class NewsDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    Context c;
    String jsonUrl;
    RecyclerView rv;

    String TAG = "Bla bla";
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public NewsDownloader(Context c, String jsonUrl, RecyclerView rv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.jsonUrl = jsonUrl;
        this.rv = rv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Please wait...");
        pd.setMessage("Loading list of news sources");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return download();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonData) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonData);

        pd.dismiss();
        if(jsonData.startsWith("Error")){
            String error = jsonData;
            Toast.makeText(c, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            //parser
            new NewsParser(c, jsonData, rv).execute();
        }
    }

    private String download(){
        Object connection = Connector.connect(jsonUrl);
        if(connection.toString().startsWith("Error"))
            return connection.toString();

        try{
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
            if(con.getResponseCode()==con.HTTP_OK){
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                StringBuffer jsonData = new StringBuffer();

                while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
                    jsonData.append(line+"\n");

                br.close();
                is.close();

                Log.d(TAG, jsonData.toString());
                return jsonData.toString();

            }else {
                return "Error" + con.getResponseMessage();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error : "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**NewsViewHolder.java**

```
package com.example.user.samplebulletin;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by User on 16-03-2017.
 */

public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView title, author, date, description;
    ImageView image;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        description = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_description);
        author = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_author);
        date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_date);

        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_progressbar);
    }
}
```

**Connector.java**

```
package com.example.user.samplebulletin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by User on 16-03-2017.
 */

public class Connector {
    public static Object connect(String JSONUrl){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(JSONUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setReadTimeout(15000);
            con.setDoInput(true);

            return con;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error"+e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error"+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**NewsItem.java**

```
package com.example.user.samplebulletin;

/**
 * Created by User on 16-03-2017.
 */

public class NewsItem {
    String author, title, description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt;

    public NewsItem(String author, String title, String description, String url, String urlToImage, String publishedAt) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getUrlToImage() {
        return urlToImage;
    }

    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 03-17 21:58:01.936 22896-22896/com.example.user.samplebulletin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.user.samplebulletin, PID: 22896 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 506340012 byte allocation with 4409258 free bytes and 185MB until OOM at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) at

This indicates the issue you are having is a memory issue.

I checked the data is coming from the API and the images are huge (1612 x 806) ([image](https://cdn2.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/03/Swatch.jpg)) and this is only one. Putting a few of these in a RecyclerView will surely blow up your memory.

The option is reduce the size of the image before loading it. Picasso has an option to this `resize`

Try this:

```
    Picasso.with(c)
            .load(item.getUrlToImage())
            .resize(70, 70) //The size of your imageView
            .error(R.drawable.image_not_found)
            .into(holder.image, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
```

Comment: No, I tried resizing the pics but I am getting the exact same error

Comment: @KartikSharma check this solution to see if any of this make sense to your app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31993581

Answer (score 0):

This error is shown when setAdapter() has not been called after initializing recycler view.
You can call setAdapter() after initializing recycler view like

```
rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.news_recyclerview);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(NewsActivity.this));
ArrayList<NewsItem> mDataset = new ArrayList();
NewsAdapter mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(context,mDataset);
rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

When you refresh request is complete then add those incoming news in the mDataset. You would have to pass the reference to mDataset to NewsParser.

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isParsed) {
    super.onPostExecute(isParsed);

    pd.dismiss();
    if(isParsed){
        mDataset.addAll(newsItems);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }else
        Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```